# Can't get Raspberry Pi IP address from ADSL router connected to Ubiquiti NanoStation

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I got my Raspberry Pi today. I formatted an SD card and installed [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Raspbian) on it. I want to use the Raspberry Pi for downloading torrent files. I get into the Raspberry Pi with SSH with my MacBook. I don't have any monitor or mouse etc. to use with the Raspberry Pi. I want to use something like [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) to connect to the Raspberry Pi with my MacBook.

When I plug the Raspberry Pi with an Ethernet cable into my TP-LINK TD-W8951ND ADSL modem router, I can see the Raspberry Pi's IP address from the modem's web interface and get ssh into with the IP address. I have a Ubiquiti NanoStation on my house roof for Wi-Fi Internet service.

Here is my setup:
 1. I get Internet connectivity with the Ubiquiti NanoStation antenna on the roof from a local wireless Internet service company.
 2. The Ethernet cable come to the TP-LINK TD-W8951ND ADSL modem router from the roof. With the MacBook I can get Internet wired or wireless.
 3. I can use Internet with two devices at the same time, but I have to login my username and password for wireless Internet service if I reboot any device the session end.

When I connect my MacBook and Raspberry Pi to my TP-LINK TD-W8951ND ADSL modem router via Ethernet, they work together, and I can get the IP address of the Raspberry Pi and can ssh into it. But when I connect the Ubiquiti NanoStation's Ethernet cable to my TP-LINK TD-W8951ND ADSL modem router, I lose the Raspberry Pi's IP address. I can't even use the TP-LINK TD-W8951ND ADSL modem router's web interface, can't access to TP-LINK router, and the Ubiquiti NanoStation prompt me to get into the service company's Mikrotik modem interface. And I get a different IP address when I connect to the Internet. I use [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) on my ADSL router which has four ethernet ports.

Before connecting to the Internet with Ubiquiti NanoStation, 
I can access the Raspberry Pi with the 192.168.1.103 IP address on the TP-LINK router. After connecting to the Internet with Ubiquiti NanoStation the IP address doesn't work, and I can't access the TP-LINK router.

How can I solve this problem? I can connect the Raspberry Pi into a monitor and Internet for installing VNC on the Raspberry Pi and other packages for use with my MacBook Pro for once. I want to setup VNC once and use Raspberry Pi with my MacBook always with VNC. Since I have to login username and password for the Wi-Fi Internet service, I must use VNC to login when needed.

I read about giving a static IP address to the Raspberry Pi, but I couldn't try it when I am logged into the Internet - I lose connection with my Raspberry Pi and ADSL router.

If I make the Raspberry Pi's IP address static and use no-ip, dyndns etc. DNS service with port forwarding, will it work after connecting to the Internet with Ubiquiti NanoStation? Can I get into the Raspberry Pi with VNC when I connect it into the ADSL router with an Ethernet cable?

Comment: It is difficult to work out what you are actually asking. If you want the Pi to have a fixed address, I suggest you use your router to give a fixed IP to the Pi MAC. Incidentally, as you are using a Mac, you may want to install 'netatalk' on the Pi, which will let you connect with appletalk afp://192.168.1.103 (or whatever your Pi is using).

Answer (score 1):

This technically is not an answer but a very long comment - but I only have 26 reputation currently.

Has the TP-Link modem worked previously with the Ubiquiti nanostation? Their may be a problem with a HTTP proxy.

Finding the Raspberry Pi's new IP address that is an easier problem to solve. Adding your new IP address after you connect the TP-Lick and the nanostation together to your question might help there - does it begin with '192.168.1.' etc.

Anyway, my solution here is to use nmap - available for Mac *(I am guessing that is what you are running on your Macbook)* [here](http://nmap.org/download.html#macosx) and [here](http://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html) .

Once installed, connect the Raspberry Pi, run in terminal this command: `nmap -A 192.168.1.1-20`
This will scan all the IPs on between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.20

As you have ssh on your Pi, the output for the IP address should have something like this:

`22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 4 (protocol 2.0)`

If you have root or Administrator permissions on your Mac, run this instead:

`sudo nmap -O 192.168.1.1-20`

Then look for this to find the IP address

`Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.??`

`MAC Address: ??:??:??:??:??:?? (Raspberry Pi Foundation)`

I find this method useful for finding IP addresses, but it is also useful for checking for security flaws with your computer so you can find a solution.

And finally, to use VNC, follow the instructions here: http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server

Answer (score 0):

raspberry pi is ieee 802.11ac standard. The wifi router which we have been using for the ADSL connection is 802.1b/g/n/a standard so it will get problem connecting to network. If you comply with both standard match then it will work perfectly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any Raspberry can connect to g/n Wifi networks.